# JSLint errors: "

Tags: javascript, optimization, jslint

I am attempting to rewrite a plug-in so that it will pass JSLint. I'm about 3 lines into a 300 line script, and I'm stuck here:

```
   var __slice = [].slice,
       __indexOf = [].indexOf || function (item) {
        var i = 0,
            l = this.length;
        for (i < l) <<<<< this is where the error is
                  {
                    if (i in this && this[i] === item)
                    return i; 
                  }
      i+=1;
      return -1;};
```

The error is

```
 "Expected ';' and instead saw ')'.
        for (i < l)
```

I'm not sure how to rewrite this to fit their conventions. Suggestions?

Comment: `for(; i < l; )` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem related to JSLint, but your for loop syntax is incorrect.

The syntax for a for loop looks like this:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment);
```

an example:

```
for (var i = i; i < 10; i++)
```

So in your situation you should either use:

```
for (; i < L ;)
```

Notice the omitting of the initialization and increment part.

Or better yet, use a while loop:

```
while ( i < L )
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd gutted it inadvertently in an attempt to keep JSLint happy about earlier errors. Have re-written according this helpful guide, and moved on to new errors: http://www.impressivewebs.com/javascript-for-loop/

Comment: @Ali You are welcome. A piece of advise always try to make you code work first and then try to optimize it and clean it up. With time you will gain experience and your code will be optimized from the start.

Comment: JSLint doesn't accept the `for (; i < L ;)` form either. You have to either specify all three clauses, or none at all (`for (;;)`). In the example here a while loop is the best solution. But there are other cases - like missing just the initialization - where you have to trade off simpler code (for loop) vs. making JSLint happy (while loop).